# How fast are EC/2 nodes between each other?

Tags: amazon-ec2, nosql, riak

I am looking to setup Amazon EC/2 nodes on rails with Riak. I am looking to be able to sync the riak DBs and if the cluster gets a query, to be able to tell where the data lies and retrieve it quickly. In your opinion(s), is EC/2 fast enough between nodes to query a Riak DB, return the results, and get them back to the client in a timely manner? I am new to all of this, so please be kind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a Riak expert, but if you keep all of your EC2 instances in the same availability zone you should get more than adequate performance.  AWS has a gigabit internal network and people have been able to get the full gigabit out of it; see [this blog post](http://blog.rightscale.com/2007/10/28/network-performance-within-amazon-ec2-and-to-amazon-s3/) for an example.

Comment: Thank you Gareth! I have continued my search and am thinking about putting the riak datastore on an external EBS volume for better performace and so that if an instance is deleted, I don't lose the data on that ec2-instance.  I suppose that would mean I start with one instance attached to multiple EBS disks, and then add instances and spread out the disks among them as I need performance. Am I thinking about this the right way?

Comment: @tesmar, your approach sounds good - note that you can make an EBS volume pretty much as big as you like (although you pay per GB), so you may not need multiple volumes - again - I don't konw enough about Riak to answer that properly.

Answer (score 0):

Marc-Andre,

Your best bet is to ask on the mailing list: http://lists.basho.com/mailman/listinfo/riak-users_lists.basho.com

There's also lots of information on the wiki: http://wiki.basho.com/display/RIAK/Home

Comment: Thank you Sean! (This is Tyler from raleigh ruby). I am new to all of this and will mail the team with a similar question.

Comment: Actually, I have just gotten riak setup and am beginning to play with some of its features. I am going to have to get my rails app setup to connect with EC2 so that I can deploy another instance on the fly. Of course, I am still learning how all of that really "works", so off I go to read more!